# How to put input box with some icons on the right side of a header bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `icon` on the left side of a bar, on the right side I have an `input` and some other icons. The `input` is too close to the right, and the icon should be on same line as `input`.

What can I do?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <ul class="w3-ul">
      <li class="w3-xxxlarge w3-blue">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>&nbsp;Home
        <div class="w3-large" style="float: right;">
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="searchbox" type="text">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want like this?

[image]

if yes then

```
<div class="w3-container">
  <ul class="w3-ul">
    <li class="w3-xxxlarge w3-blue"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>&nbsp;Home
      <div class="w3-large" style="float: right;">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size: 40px;"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size: 40px;"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size: 40px;"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size: 40px;"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-large" style="float: right;">
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="searchbox" type="text">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT (based on comment):**

- Switched to `.w3-ul` to flex and placed `input` & `icon` on another `li`.
- Set `justify-content: space-between;` on `.w3-ul` for input & icon right alignment.
- Removed `float: right;` from `.w3-large`.

```css
ul.w3-ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="w3-container">
  <ul class="w3-ul">
    <li class="w3-xxxlarge w3-blue"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home
    </li>
    <li class="w3-large">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="searchbox" type="text">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but solution is partial as inputbox should be aligned on the right with another icon

Comment: Added flex to container for right alignment and also included same icon on the right just as example, let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">

  <ul class="w3-ul">
    <li class="w3-xxxlarge w3-blue">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>&nbsp;Home


    <span class="w3-large pull-right" >
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="searchbox" type="text">
      <span class="w3-xxxlarge w3-blue">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      </span>
    </span>


    </li>
  </ul>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```